# Accessing column in a dataframe using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am working on SPARK 1.6.1 version using SCALA and facing a unusual issue.  When creating a new column using an existing column created during same execution getting "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException".
**WORKING:**.

```
 val resultDataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("FirstColumn",lit(2021)).withColumn("SecondColumn",when($"FirstColumn" - 2021 === 0, 1).otherwise(10))
    resultDataFrame.printSchema().
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
val resultDataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("FirstColumn",lit(2021)).withColumn("SecondColumn",when($"FirstColumn" - **max($"FirstColumn")** === 0, 1).otherwise(10))
resultDataFrame.printSchema().
```

Here i am creating my SecondColumn using the FirstColumn created during the same execution. Question is why it does not work while using avg/max functions.  Please let me know how can i resolve this problem.

Comment: max (avg/sum, etc) should be used in a grouped DataFrame (i.e. after a groupBy) or with an `.over(window)` clause.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use aggregate functions together with "normal" columns, the functions should come after a `groupBy` or with a Window definition clause. Out of these cases they make no sense. Examples:

```
val result = df.groupBy($"col1").max("col2").as("max") // This works
```

In the above case, the resulting DataFrame will have both "col1" and "max" as columns.

```
val max = df.select(min("col2"), max("col2"))
```

This works because there are only aggregate functions in the query. However, the following will not work:

```
val result = df.filter($"col1" === max($"col2"))
```

because I am trying to mix a non aggregated column with an aggregated column.

If you want to compare a column with an aggregated value, you can try a join:

```
val maxDf = df.select(max("col2").as("maxValue"))
val joined = df.join(maxDf)
val result = joined.filter($"col1" === $"maxValue").drop("maxValue")
```

Or even use the simple value:

```
val maxValue = df.select(max("col2")).first.get(0)
val result = filter($"col1" === maxValue)
```